# Python and Java in internal command

Tags: java, python-2.7, python-3.4

I have installed java and using it in internal command with variable name:PATH and variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin . Now i want add python to internal command. What variable name do I give so that it works.I tried with Name: PTH and Value:C:\Python34; its not working.

Comment: there's a relative post at the superuser Forum
http://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a new variable. Append the pythen path to PATH variable. Separate them with a semicolon.

Eg:

```
PATH=C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Python34
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable name, for example MY_PYTHEN=C:\Pythen34 . Then you need to add the variable name into system variable PATH such as,

PATH = ...;%MY_PYTHEN%

PATH is a Windows system default variable.